# What is meant by the tag "reference"?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

The [reference](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) tag has no description yet.  Is it intended to be used for a question that asks for a reference where one might learn more about a certain topic, or document one's intuitive understanding about a topic?

For comparison, Academia has a tag called ["reference-request,"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) and that's how I see it used there.  The official description says:

> Questions requesting an answer supported by reliable evidence and including citations to said evidence. This is in contrast to questions requesting answers based mainly on personal experience.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497417/correct-use-of-the-pronoun-reference) should fit it.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Not quite... I proposed we ban the "list request" tag on the main site. There was one question on the main site that I had to retag to something else before we ban the tag. The closest tag relevant to that particular question was the "online resources". Even so, it should be closed and deleted for it is off topic on the main, and, at the same time, very old to be migrated to meta. All other questions with the "list request" tag have other tags as well, so a ban of "list request" tag won't break the site.